# SwiftUI: How can I set a color to .foregroundColor() by using a String? i.e. "green" --> Color.green

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, types, swiftui

So I have this String "green" inside a constant (*lernset.color*). I would like to set a `.foregroundColor()` to a symbol (systemName: "folder") inside of a list, so that it has the same color as written inside the constant (*lernset.color*).
The problem I get: I dont know how to convert this constant (*lernset.color*) which has the datatype of a String into the datatype of Color.
I already tried:

1. ...   `.foregroundColor(Color.lernset.color)`
2. ...   `.foregroundColor(Color.String(lernset.color))`
3. I also tried assigning the constant to a variable... but

nothing worked.

[ So normally you would type: `.foregroundColor(Color.green)`
But in this case I want the List to automatically adapt, so that the Color could change the way the constant (*lernset.color*) changes...

**Thank you for your help in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Color(lernset.color)
```

It only works if the `String` value of `lernset.color` is defined as a `Color Set` in `Assets`

This

```
Color.lernset.color
```

or

```
Color.green
```

References a `static` variable. You would need something like

```
extension Color{
    static let yourColor: Color = Color("nameHere")
}
```

Then you can call

```
Color.yourColor
```

With "nameHere" being the name of a `Color Set`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a string you can add an extension to Color :

```
extension Color {
    static subscript(name: String) -> Color {
        switch name {
            case "green":
                return Color.green
            case "white":
                return Color.white
            case "black":
                return Color.black
            default:
                return Color.accentColor
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
Color[lernset.color]
```